# Rails admin navigation_label translation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localization, rails-admin, rails-i18n

I'm localizing Rails app with Rails Admin using I18n. In some models (`Good < ActiveRecord`) Rails admin configured as follows:

```
rails_admin do
  label = 'Good'
  label_plural = 'Goods'
  navigation_label = 'Settings'
  navigation_icon = 'icon-settings'
end
```

I know that `label` localization can be stored in `config/locales/en.yml` (Translations for Active Record Models) as follows:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      good:
        one: Good
        few: Goods
        many: Goods
        other: Goods
```

The question is: how can I store and use locale for navigation_label? (Can't find the answer on rails admin wiki page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way I got it to work.  Define your label as:

```
NAV_SETTINGS = Proc.new { I18n.t('admin.navigation_labels.settings') }
```

Then, when you make the call in your model configuration to use the labels, use:

```
navigation_label NAV_SETTINGS
```

Then, of course, set your config/en.yml like:

```
en:
  admin:
    navigation_labels:
      settings: Settings
```

But in terms of having RailsAdmin do it for you, I haven't encountered it.

I have not tried this defining Rails Admin config in the model itself, but I know it works when defining things in `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb`, so should work here as well.

Comment: I don't know exactly why this way does not work, but it seems that in my project navigation_label loads before than other translations than default. So they are always got default translation.

Comment: @pasha.zhukov I updated my answer; thinking on this again, I did encounter that very problem, but I was able to work around it.

Comment: thank you, appreciate your help. I managed to work your previous version. Problem was in duplicating keys in yaml dictionary and it was the reason why some other keys was not loaded properly.